# Win7 all applications run in 640x480

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have no idea how to fix this, i am using a virtual machine in virtualbox and can't change the resolutions when i run an exe (Game for example)

If anyone has a solutions please help!

[win7 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efBRC.jpg)

[ingame image (fullscreen shows black borders)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlJDg.png)

Comment: I'm assuming your Windows VM is running in a higher resolution, correct?  Can you take a screen shot, and post it in an updated to your question?

Comment: done posted the images